# How do I change an attribute value in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following script

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter => 'mysql', :database => 'development', :username => 'appAccount', :password => '------', :socket => '/tmp/mysql.sock')

class ProcessQueue < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

The tutorial I'm using claims the following should work.

```
updateQ = ProcessQueue.find(:all, :conditions => "photoID = '234'")
updateQ.ExIfQ = 1
updateQ.save
```

updateQ has the following data

```
ProcessQueue id: 104, photoID: 234, ExIfQ: 0, Providor: 0, created_at: "2009-12-30 14:42:01", updated_at: "2009-12-30 14:42:01"
```

But when running updateQ.ExIfQ = 1 I get an error saying the method does not exist

NoMethodError: undefined method `'ExIfQ=' for #<Array:0x102207c60>`

The error makes sense. I'm trying to make a change on an array. Therefore I can only assume either I'm wrong or the tutorial is wrong :)

I was wondering if someone could tell me how I should be making this update?

p.s this is a background script running in my rails application.

Thanks

Comment: I don't completely understand what you're trying to do. ProcessQueue.find(:all, ...) returns an array of ProcessQueue objects, so you can't set an object attribute and save without first extracting the object from the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few approaches to this that work, each with their various quirks.

The quick and dirty method is to use update_all to reassign the attribute:

```
ProcessQueue.update_all('ExIfQ=1', :photoID => 234)
```

Iterate over all those found using find:

```
ProcessQueue.find(:all, :conditions => { :photoID => 234 }).each do |pq|
  pq.ExIfQ = 1
  pq.save!
end
```

Find one and manipulate it directly:

```
if (pq = ProcessQueue.find_by_photoID(234))
  pq.ExIfQ = 1
  pq.save!
end
```

As a note, try not to spell out your conditions when declaring them using array with placeholders or hash-style. It's much safer since it will do the type conversion for you, as required.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only going to be one of these that is a query result, use:

```
updateQ = ProcessQueue.find(:first, :conditions => "photoID = '234'")
```

Comment: i do not understand the down-vote. In the OP code, if you replace :all by :first, as mentioned in this answer, the code will work.

Answer (score 1):

`find` method returns array of objects.

You can add `first`:

```
updateQ = ProcessQueue.find(:all, :conditions => "photoID = '234'").first
```

and then your example will work, or iterate over array

```
updateQ = ProcessQueue.find(:all, :conditions => "photoID = '234'")
updateQ.each do |u|
  up.ExIfQ = 1
  up.save
end
```